# Как учесть отсутствие символа в начале паттерна в регулярных выражениях в python 3?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Использую python 3.

Есть ini фалй типа:

```
;elok_p_crm_i01="2017-12-23 19:36:38"+"2017-12-24 01:36:38"
elok_p_crm_i02="2013-01-23 11:36:38"+"2017-02-24 01:36:38"
elok_p_crm_i03="2012-12-23 23:36:38"+"2017-01-24 01:36:38"
```

Мне нужно найти все тройки значений, но без строк с ";". Это комментарии в ini файлах.

Мой паттерн:

```
pattern = r"([\w-]+)=([\"][\d-]+\s[\d:]+[\"])\+([\"][\d-]+\s[\d:]+[\"])"
```

Пробовал добавлять [^;] в начале, но он не действует, видимо потому что питон просто берёт субстринг начиная сразу после ";" который уже подходит по паттерну.

Как мне избежать строчек с ";"?

Comment: является ли ваш INI файл - нормальным INI файлом, в котором обычно должны присутствовать секции `[Section_Name]`?

Comment: Да. Но я так понимаю - с этим паттерном названия секций всеравно отпадают

Comment: тогда можно воспользоваться готовым модулем - ConfigParser и не мучаться с RegEx'ами... Приведите __воспроизводимый__ пример INI файла, с несколькими секциями и примером того что вам надо получить. Тогда можно будет сделать рабочий вариант с использованием ConfigParser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^(?<![;])([\w_]+)=([\"][\d-]+\s[\d:]+[\"])\+([\"][\d-]+\s[\d:]+[\"])$", re.M)
```

Это такой же паттерн, как у тебя, за исключением нескольких деталей.

- Начинается символом начала строки ^
- Заканчивается символом конца строки $
- Конструкция `^(?<![;])` - это отрицательный просмотр назад. Он говорит, что будут выбраны все конструкции, перед которыми НЕ стоит ;
- Модификатор re.M говорит, что выполняется многострочный поиск.

Пример использования:

```
text = ''';elok_p_crm_i01="2017-12-23 19:36:38"+"2017-12-24 01:36:38"
elok_p_crm_i02="2013-01-23 11:36:38"+"2017-02-24 01:36:38"
elok_p_crm_i03="2012-12-23 23:36:38"+"2017-01-24 01:36:38"'''

pattern.findall(text)
```

Выведет

```
[('elok_p_crm_i02', '"2013-01-23 11:36:38"', '"2017-02-24 01:36:38"'), ('elok_p_crm_i03', '"2012-12-23 23:36:38"', '"2017-01-24 01:36:38"')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать "негативный" блок просмотра назад, который отфильтрует совпадения, перед которыми находится `;`, за которым следует граница слова:

```
r'(?<!^;)\b([\w-]+)=([\"][\d-]+\s[\d:]+[\"])\+([\"][\d-]+\s[\d:]+[\"])'
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

См. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/y9GJar/1).

Если ожидаемые совпадения занимают целую строку, рекомендую добавить `$`, символ конца строки ([ещё одно демо](https://regex101.com/r/y9GJar/2)).

Если текст вчитывается целиком (`.read()`), то понадобится модификатор `re.MULTILINE`, чтобы `^` находил начало строки, а `$` — конец строки (а не целого текста).